# CTRL+Click (aka Hyperlink) on .xml not working

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, struts

I'm using Eclipse Ganymede & Struts 1.2. Here's my `.xml` code:

```
<action path="/xxxxx/TestAjax"
        type="aaa.bbb.ccc.view.TestAjax"
        name="ddd.eee"
        validate="false">
    <forward name="ready"
           path="/WEB-INF/jsp/pg/hhh/test.jsp"
           redirect="false">
    </forward>
</action>
```

Previously, I can CTRL+Click on the "aaa.bbb.ccc.view.TestAjax" and the file "TestAjax.java" will open automatically. But after installing new fresh Eclipse, I can't no longer do that.

So my question:

1. Is it setting? If yes how and where?
2. Is it plugin? If yes how and where?

My assumption is plugin. After googling, I try to install Amateras plugin (tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor_2.2.0.jar). When I open the .xml using "Amateras XML Editor", I still can't get the hyperlink working.

Another question is, is it possible to hyperlink on the "/WEB-INF/jsp/pg/hhh/test.jsp" as well?

Without this feature, I has to CTRL+R on the file name which is troublesome since there are plenty of same file name (in different path).

Comment: I just found out something strange. The hyperlink is actually a little bit working. If I have several action mapping on the same file, only the last one can be hyperlinked

Comment: Can you do a fresh build and validate the entire project once?

Comment: I had Project > Clean (Build Automatically checked). And how to validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

1. Install WTP XML Editor plugin
2. Install FileLinks plugin

Now everything is perfect.